# Kivy. Text provider error

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Start a simple sample of "Hello world". And got an error.

```
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Is it mean that I have no some font libs? Tried to install dev libs of actual fonts in system.

System: Centos. Python version 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the SDL TTF library required by PyGame. On Ubuntu, this is a system package called "libsdl-ttf2.0-dev". I think on CentOS it is called "SDL_ttf-devel". You can ensure you have the rest of the PyGame dependencies installed by looking at this [PyGame install for RedHat page](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileRedHat).

Comment: In my case this just happened because I had skipped the step of installing pygame. I suspect this would be a common reason for seeing this error.

Answer (score 6):

According to [`kivy.core.text`](http://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/core/text.html) code:

```
...

# Load the appropriate provider

Label = core_select_lib('text', (
    ('pygame', 'text_pygame', 'LabelPygame'),
    ('sdlttf', 'text_sdlttf', 'LabelSDLttf'),
    ('pil', 'text_pil', 'LabelPIL'),
))

if 'KIVY_DOC' not in os.environ:
    if not Label:
        from kivy.logger import Logger
        import sys
        Logger.critical('App: Unable to get a Text provider, abort.')
        sys.exit(1)

...
```

, your system is missing required package. Install one of them first.

Comment: is it python or system packages?

Comment: @Lissomort, All are python library. But they may depends on some system packages.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install Pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me. this should appear in the kivy dependencies page.

Answer (score 1):

just be sure that you already have all dependencies installed, look at the [installation section of the kivy wiki](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post. I though of adding this if some body is searching for the same issue...

For Fedora 25 the best is to install "pygame"

```
dnf install pygame
dnf install pygame-devel
```

For me this resolved the issue.

Further to setup working Kivy environment in Fedora (I use Fedora 25), make sure all the dependencies are installed as below,

```
 dnf install make
 dnf install mercurial
 dnf install automake
 dnf install gcc
 dnf install gcc-c++
 dnf install SDL_ttf-devel
 dnf install SDL_mixer-devel
 dnf install khrplatform-devel
 dnf install mesa-libGLES
 dnf install mesa-libGLES-devel
 dnf install gstreamer-plugins-good
 dnf install gstreamer
 dnf install gstreamer-python
 dnf install mtdev-devel
 dnf install python-devel
 dnf install python-pip
 dnf install pygame
 dnf install pygame-devel
```

I mentioned those as separate commands as some of these comes by default.

Ref: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#fedora