# Kivy on Mac 10.10 Yosemite using PyCharm CE

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

As a try to run Kivy's "Hello World" example, I get this error:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/mateusenricosrecaruso/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-05-14_9.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!
sdl2 - ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/text/_text_sdl2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
Referenced from: /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/text/_text_sdl2.so
Reason: image not found
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/text/text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

il - ImportError: No module named PIL
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 8, in <module>
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know if I should download PyGame or something like that (even though I tried and it kept saying that the installation couldn't be completed due to existence of MacPorts or Fink.
I used to use Spyder2 on Anaconda for Python3.4 - but now I'm supposed to use the older Python version to make a college's project.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you have PIL installed? http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm

Comment: I guess not, but if I try to download it by "pip install pil", it always says that no matching distribuition of PIL was found

Comment: A related question on how to install PIL on mac: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion

Comment: I'd also try the development library of SDL TTF for your system from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/ - per related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697195/kivy-text-provider-error

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

To install `PIL` paste the following line in your command line.

```
pip install Pillow
```