# Kivy running error. Unable to find any valuable Text provider

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Windows 10 machine.
Two python version installed. 3.6.5 and 3.5. Also 3.4 was installed and removed.
As this is my first steps, maybe I messed around with all these installations.

A very first basic kivy application.

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label


class HelloKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hi')


hellowKivy = HelloKivy()

hellowKivy.run()
```

When running the app this is the error:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\Oren\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-04-16_40.txt [INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.0 [INFO   ] Python: v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] [INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded [INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored) [CRITICAL] Text: Unable to find any valuable Text provider. sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.   File "C:\Users\Oren\venv\HellowKivy2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\Oren\venv\HellowKivy2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'   File "C:\Users\Oren\venv\HellowKivy2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\Oren\venv\HellowKivy2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] App: Unable to get a Text provider, abort.


As far as I understand everything is installed. Here is the CMD opuput.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>.\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools**

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (10.0.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.31.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (39.0.1)

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>.\python.exe -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew**

Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.sdl2 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.1.17)
Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.glew in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (223)

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>.\python.exe -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer**

Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.gstreamer in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.1.12)

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>.\python.exe -m pip install kivy.deps.angle**

Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.angle in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (0.1.6)

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>.\python.exe -m pip install kivy**

Requirement already satisfied: kivy in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from kivy) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from kivy) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from kivy) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (2018.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy) (2.6)
```

I use pcCharm.

Edit:

[image: Check the project Interpreter setting screen shot]

pip and setuptools not the latest versions. Is that a problem?

I have tried to upgrade as describe [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line)

but when I try `pip --version` there is an error

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts\pip.exe" --version'
```

not sure what is means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy. Text provider error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697195/kivy-text-provider-error)

Comment: @eyllanesc. What does it mean? what should i do? Also,  [the installation guide](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) indicates kivy needs to be installed for each version. So yes, I have installed it for both.

Comment: Check the answers of the answer that I indicate is duplicated.

Comment: @eyllanesc. Sorry, I do not understand. I do not see any answer referring duplicate Kivy in the provided link.

Comment: Your problem and the previous problem indicate that they lack the Text Provider, and as I see in the previous answers, they indicate that it needs to install a suitable library, for example, install Pillow, see this: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html

Comment: @eyllanesc As describe [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/installation.html) `pip install Pillow` didnt work. However, looks like `easy_install Pillow` installed Pillow 5.1.0. Please see my edit to the post. In addition, Pillow is not there. Should it be?

Comment: Do not use the cmd, because that pip points to another python: "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\python.exe" instead you are using a venv as seen in your screenshot, pycharm allows to install packages. To do this, follow this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: @eyllanesc OK. This helped, although I'm confused about all these interpreter copies (I see some more copies of python.exe), and why some packages were installed and some not. Not sure whether it is a pyCharm  env behaviour, or Python or the fact I was messing around.

Comment: In the image that shows the following: `Python3.6 (HellowKivy2) c:\Users\Oren\venv\...`, 
on the side there should be a button with the plus sign, press, search pyllow and install it.

Answer (score 0):

As *eyllanesc* was suggesting, some packages were missing for the project local interpreter (maybe the term is wrong). 
Installing the packages via pyCharm File | Setting | Project Interpreter, solved the issue.
Has to install kivi dependencies (sdl2,glew) as well as Pillow.

Comment: the term is correct, but a better name is virtualenv. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/